# How to extract an unique value that automatically sets in a re-navigated request's parameter

Tags: jmeter

I have the below POST request on a certain log in test plan. (Here’s the screenshot of the result tree listener)

[image]

Once the POST request successfully goes through, a subsequent auto-re-navigated GET request automatically fires following that.

[image]

In the re-navigated request there is an auto-generated parameter “code” with a value and every time it changes. Since this value is not available in previous request's response is there anyway to extract it to a variable?

Comment: Does this `code` appear in sub-sample response? If yes, there is an option in post-processor named `Apply to` = `Sub-samples only`.

Comment: Thanks a lot lucas-nguyen  . It worked with the option main sample and sub samples and using a regex to extract it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My expectation is that it is in the response but in [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers), not in the body.

So the server sends the URL with the `code` parameter via [Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location) header so you should be able to extract it from there.

[image]

More information: [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)